# How do I create a 'for' loop to create a vector of columns which contain NAs in R?

Tags: r

I'm attempting to create a vector of column names which contain one or more NA values using a for loop, but am not having success.

```
hasnas <- c()

for (i in 1:length(data)){
  if(sum(is.na(data[,i]))>0){
    hasnas <- append(hasnas,names(data[,i]))
 
  }
         
  
}
  
>hasnas
>NULL
```

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: cleaner code : `if( any(is.na(data[,i])) ){...}`

Answer (score 2):

Couple of base R options :

```
#Option 1 
hasnas <- names(data)[colSums(is.na(data)) > 0]

#Option 2
hasnas <- names(Filter(function(x) any(is.na(x)), data))
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use a loop, but R's `apply` function:

```
d <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = c(1, NA), c = c(NA, NA), d = 1:2)

o <- apply(d, 2, function(x) any(is.na(x)))

names(o[sapply(o, isTRUE)])

[1] "b" "c"
```

Comment: The last line could be `names(d)[o]`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `names(data[,i])` to `names(data)[i]`. See a full reprex below:

```r
data <- iris
data[["Sepal.Length"]][sample(100, 10)] <- NA
data[["Species"]][sample(100, 10)] <- NA

hasnas <- c()

for (i in 1:length(data)) {
  if(any(is.na(data[, i]))) {
    hasnas <- append(hasnas, names(data)[i])
  }
}

hasnas
#> [1] "Sepal.Length" "Species"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There's a concise (and elegant, I think) way you can achieve this by using purrr

```
data <- tibble(
  a = rep(NA, 10),
  b = rnorm(10),
  c = rep(NA, 10)
)
```

Loading purrr package: `library(purrr)`

```
names(data)[map_lgl(data, ~any(is.na(.x)))]
[1] "a" "c"
```